# Why does writing into my string not work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following Code is not working. I get an error at the command `cin >> h`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string h = " ";

    cout << "hi" << endl;
    cin >> h;
    cout << h << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes? And? What happens?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What really happens?

Comment: Don't use
`system("PAUSE"); `

Comment: well i see the prob with my question. 
I forgot to mention that it said cin >> h;
was an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random guessing:

You forgot to `#include <string>`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include `<string>` and C++ punished you for that.

Ah, but every man and his dog should know that by not including `<string>`, you were using the default `>>` operator, that has well know issues with strings.

C++'s "leave the progammers free to shoot themselves in the foot" philosophy at its best.

C++ lore tells the unfortunate wandereds should use `getline` instead of `cin >>`, but there have been heated debates among scholars on this fine doctrine point.

Comment: all I have to say is 
lol = true